# Staking and Unstaking methods or commands?

Tags: staking

I create account like below..

[image: command : cleos get account (account_name)]

And its balance is...
[image]

I knew that I takes 3 days to unstake values..

So, My First question is that how can I unstake some amounts and put them my balance? (for example, change 1290.8545 SYS to 1300.8545 SYS) Could you provide some examples of command or actions?

And my Second question is that What is difference between Staked: and Delegated:?

Thank you for reading my silly questions! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Staked and delegated both assume the same staked status of the SYS token in this case.  Staked assumes that you reserve the ability to vote on producers.  Delegated assumes that you elect what is known as a "proxy" to vote on your behalf.  This logic can be seen in the eosio.system.hpp

```
/** * Total vote weight delegated to this voter. */ 
double proxied_vote_weight= 0; /// the total vote weight delegated to this 
voter as a proxy bool is_proxy = 0; /// whether the voter is a proxy for others
```

https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/blob/master/contracts/eosio.system/eosio.system.hpp#L99

Also, here is the cleos command and positional arguments for the system voteproducer proxy command.

```
cleos system voteproducer proxy voter proxy

Positional Arguments
voter TEXT - The voting account
proxy TEXT - The proxy account
```

https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-system-voteproducer-proxy

As for unstaking, I've found the cleos command for that in the developer's documentation as well:

**system undelegatebw**
Undelegate bandwidth

Positional Arguments

```
from TEXT - The account undelegating bandwidth
receiver TEXT - The account to undelegate bandwidth from
unstake_net_quantity TEXT - The amount of EOS to undelegate for network bandwidth
unstake_cpu_quantity TEXT - The amount of EOS to undelegate for CPU bandwidth
```

So the command may look something like:

```
cleos system undelegatebw FROM RECEIVER unstake_net_quantity unstake_cpu_quantity
```